# Error al encontrar volley:volley.1.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

### Por que sucede el error volley:volley.1.1.1.##

Me esta dando ese error, por lo que me explicó una profe es algo relacionado con las imágenes pero yo no estoy utilizando esa clase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte de eso constantemente me aparece esta línea como errónea en las dependencias de android, no se si tenga relación con el error anterior o afecte de alguna forma al correcto funcionamiento del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes implementar en tu tus dependencias

```
   implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```

el error que te presenta en la otra implementacion es
La versión 28 (destinada a Android Pie e inferior) es la última versión de la biblioteca de soporte heredada, por lo que le recomendamos que migre a las bibliotecas de AndroidX cuando use Android Q y siga adelante. El IDE puede ayudar con esto: Refactorizar > Migrar a AndroidX...
debes cambiar por

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```